# Performance of Immutable vs. Mutable Objects?

Tags: object

I've long heard that immutable objects are "the way to go"--and I have no disagreement in terms of development. However, it seems to me that if you want to write an efficient program you *must* use mutable objects--i.e. you must garbage collect yourself!

I have first hand experience with this, where I have written a program that consumed numerous resources (~8-10 GB of RAM per run). I initially ran where I did no re-use of objects (just new everything--immutable) and it ran but my memory profile just kept keep growing.

I then switched to mutable objects (custom objects)--where I reused objects on an object stack rather than constantly instantiating new ones. This greatly improved the memory usage (kept it rather constant rather than a constant growth with run time).

I'm curious: I always hear the benefits of immutable objects, but never the performance downside. Are there? Are they (mutable objects) practical or only in certain situations?

Comment: We're gonna need way more details in order to provide an answer here. What language? what type of application? what datatypes? etc... I would actually say you've already answered your own question that the primary use case for immutable objects is to prevent unintended side-effects as projects grow in size. Occasional performance benefits sometimes come from easier static analysis and therefore better compiler optimization, but many classic algorithms considered "optimal" operate on data in-place (mutable). Also it kinda sounds like your immutable-only program may have just had a leak.

Comment: @Aaron I _was_ thinking in general...you almost provided an answer in that "memory-in-place" requires mutable objects. I was just wondering because I see so much push for immutable object representation when that fails in terms of the memory model...

Comment: @Aaron but at the same time, we push so much to libraries that we generally don't care about what objects we create...

Comment: @Aaron but if you're asking about my specific example, it'd be hard to explain and it wouldn't be a question--I already know that I needed mutable objects to do what I wanted. I'm wondering if others have come to this realization...and maybe that makes this not a question so fair enough.